# Maven Build Failure. ClientProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

So, I've setup my "setting.xml" file properly with host and port. Now, whenever I am trying to do "mvn clean", it is giving me the below error.
Help please.

Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): TransferFailedException: ClientProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

Comment: You most probably experience network problems or are behind a corporate proxy. Run Maven with `-X` to get more info.

Comment: Thank you for replying. 
It was exactly what you said. Changing the Proxy and Port in "setting.xml" did the job.